# Waiting for async operation to complete

Tags: c#, windows, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8

I have a question about how asynchronous methods work on c#. I am trying to get the convertAddressToCoordinate method to set the myLocation variable to a GeoCoordinate. However, the compareDistance method is called even before the myLocation value is set. How can I ensure that the myLocation value is not null before I call compareDistance()?

```
public GeoCoordinate myLocation = null;

public void returnClosestCurrent(string address)
 {

     convertAddressToCoordinate(address);
     compareDistance(myLocation);

 }

 public void convertAddressToCoordinate(string add)
 {
    WebClient wc = new WebClient();
     wc.DownloadStringCompleted += wc_DownloadStringCompleted;
     wc.DownloadStringAsync(new Uri("http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=1600+bay+st&sensor=false"));


 }

 void wc_DownloadStringCompleted(object sender, DownloadStringCompletedEventArgs e)
 {

    XDocument xdoc = XDocument.Parse(e.Result, LoadOptions.None);

     var data = from query in xdoc.Descendants("location")
                 select new Location
                 {
                     lat = (string)query.Element("lat"),
                     lng = (string)query.Element("lng")
                 };

     GeoCoordinate destinationGeo = new GeoCoordinate(Convert.ToDouble(data.ElementAt(0).lat), Convert.ToDouble(data.ElementAt(0).lng));

     myLocation = destinationGeo;


 }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use the await keyword for getting values of async task

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/hh156528.aspx

Comment: Where would I place the await keyword in the code though? DownloadStringAsync() doesn't have a return type.

Comment: I think the better way is to move the `compareDistance` method in the downloadstring event

Answer (score 1):

Looking at your code, seems to me that the `compareDistance(myLocation);` should be called only in the end of the `wc_DownloadStringCompleted` method.

After that change, everything should work fine.

Answer (score 1):

You would want to `await` the `wc.DownloadStringAsync`

```
public async Task returnClosestCurrent(string address)
{
    await convertAddressToCoordinate(address)
              .ContinueWith(t => compareDistance(myLocation));
}

public async Task convertAddressToCoordinate(string add)
{
    WebClient wc = new WebClient();
    wc.DownloadStringCompleted += wc_DownloadStringCompleted;
    await wc.DownloadStringAsync(new Uri("http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=1600+bay+st&sensor=false"));
}
```

The pattern with `async`/`await` is the code tends to turn everything into `async`/`await`

It could be refactored to use [`WebClient.DownloadStringTaskAsync`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh138332.aspx)

```
public async Task ReturnClosestCurrent(string address)
{
    await convertAddressToCoordinate(address)
            .ContinueWith(t => compareDistance(t.Result));
}

public async Task<GeoCoordinate> ConvertAddressToCoordinate(string add)
{
    WebClient wc = new WebClient();
    wc.DownloadStringCompleted += wc_DownloadStringCompleted;
    var content = await wc.DownloadStringTaskAsync(new Uri("http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=1600+bay+st&sensor=false"));

    return ParseContent(content);
}

private GeoCoordinate ParseContent(string content)
{
    XDocument xdoc = XDocument.Parse(content, LoadOptions.None);

    var data = from query in xdoc.Descendants("location")
             select new Location
             {
                 lat = (string)query.Element("lat"),
                 lng = (string)query.Element("lng")
             };

    GeoCoordinate destinationGeo = new GeoCoordinate(Convert.ToDouble(data.ElementAt(0).lat), Convert.ToDouble(data.ElementAt(0).lng));

    return destinationGeo;
}
```

Comment: Apparently DownloadStringTaskAsync doesn't exist for Windows Phone 8!